# mysql - get explicit value and random values in one query

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Is it possible to get a specific value (like ID = 5) and in addition to that, two or three other random values from the same table?

**Here's my query:**

```
SELECT name, solution, MAX( solution ) 
FROM tracks
WHERE id !=5
GROUP BY name
ORDER BY RAND( ) 
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

**What I want to do:**
I have a quiz where I need to get three answers from the database. In my first query I'm getting the actual answer and in the second (the query above) I get the other two answer that are NOT the actual answer (ID != ).

The problem is, in my table, 4 values are the same, they have the same name, so if my acutal answer is ID = 5, there is the possibility that the query above will select the ID with 9 (it's the same name as ID = 5).

How can I avoid that?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible. Use UNION for that. ([sqlfiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0b1d3/6/0))

```
SELECT * FROM ( (
   SELECT id, name, max(solution) as solution
   FROM tracks
   WHERE id = 5
   GROUP BY name
   LIMIT 0, 1
   )
   UNION (
   SELECT id, name, solution
   FROM tracks
   WHERE id != 5
   GROUP BY name

)) tmp ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 0, 3
```

Comment: Yes, I thought about Union... I will check that!

Comment: I get an error on tmp?

Comment: @Marek123 I updated my answer: both SQL and sqlfiddle as an example.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could add a subquery to your where clause to lookup all solutions that are not the id and do not have the same solution name:

```
SELECT name, solution, MAX( solution ) 
FROM tracks
WHERE id !=5
--check that the id is not in the subquery and the name doesnt match:
AND id not in (select id from tracks t where id!=5 and t.name <> name)
GROUP BY name
ORDER BY RAND( ) 
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

Answer (score 0):

Random results are random. If you want to ensure that you don't get results with the same name as the answer, you have to filter by name.

```sql
SELECT name, solution, MAX(solution) 
FROM tracks
WHERE id != 5 AND name != (SELECT name FROM tracks WHERE id = 5)
GROUP BY name
ORDER BY RAND() 
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

Comment: this is the real deal! thank you!